# window.localStorage not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var store = window.localStorage;
   $('#accounts > li > a').click(function (e) {
                var store = window.localStorage;
                e.preventDefault();
                store.setItem('account1', $(this).html());
                alert($(this).html());
                alert(store.getItem('account1'));
   });
   ...
```

When I make a change to the link the first alert gives me the correct value but the last alert just gives me null.  I'm using Firefox 11 (very latest) and IE 9. I thought both would allow local storage.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong. It seems very simple code. I just cannot get items to store.

Here's the HTML I am using:

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn-group">
    <label style="background: none; background-color: #333; width: 120px;" 
    class="btn btn-inverse" id="account">X</label>

    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="accounts">
    <li><a data-value="00" href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="01" href="#">B</a></li>

    <li><a data-value="02" href="#">C</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="16" href="#">D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code exactly as you have it above and put it on jsfiddle. I had to improvise the HTML, since you didn't post it, but it works for me on Chrome, Safari and IE9.

I would suggest posting your HTML. That may be the problem.

Does this demo work for you?:

http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/MRLEW/

Comment: Thanks. This works !!  I will check into it more and look at the HTML.

Comment: Just added the HTML to my question.

Comment: Problem solved. I realized there was a line missing from above. This line was store.clear('locationID'); I thought that would clear the local stored locationID but it actually clears everything. Thanks for your help. Marking as accepted answer.